# Getting false divide by zero in Excel

Tags: excel, statistics

I have a column of numbers.

When I try calculating the standard deviation in Excel by using `STDEV(A1:A97)` I get a '#DIV/o!' notice. But there are no zeroes or false values in that range.

All the data is formatted as numbers with 3 decimal places.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure that you have the range correctly selected? The only case how I can reproduce #Div/0! is if I select only one cell for STDEV (as it divides by N-1 it would make sense to show this kind of error in such case). Also - sometimes even if the value is formatted as number it is still considered a text for functions. Try re-entering some of the values.

Comment: Could you please share some data.. according to your description it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The problem was some of the cells contained a carriage return after the number, so I guess Excel counted those as zero.

After using the `TRIM()` function, I was able to calculate what I needed.